# Changing on('hover') to on('click') for touchscreen devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a boolean variable called isTouchscreen and some on('hover', ...) events. If the isTouchscreen boolean variable equals true then I need to change on('hover') events to on('click') events. Is this possible?

Something like:

```
 $(".smart-suggestions").on("hover", ".option", function(){
    $('.img-container img').show();
    //and do more stuff....
 });

    if(touchscreen==true){
       //change onhover event to onclick event  
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could do it this way:

```
var evt = touchscreen ? 'click' : 'hover';

$(".smart-suggestions").on( evt, ".option", function(){/*.....*/});
```

Alternate approach if you need both events :

```
$(".smart-suggestions").on('click hover', ".option", function(event){
       /* create whatever conditions you need*/
      if( event.type=='click' && touchscreen){
            doThis();
       }else{
              doThat();
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What if the on('hover') fuction contains regular click() and hover() events? is there a way to handle those as well if isTouchscreen is true?

Comment: If isTouchscreen==true change on('hover') and hover() events TO on('click') and click()

Comment: what do you mean by `change to`?  Not being very clear. Original example will bind `click` if `touchscreen` is true, and `hover` if not

Comment: @MHZ use `.trigger(evt)` instead of `.click/.hover` and it should work.

Comment: I added another approach to answer...maybe it would help you

Comment: @Mathletics thanks for the reply, I am not sure what you mean, can you please give an example?

Comment: @MHZ  you can also use `off()` if you need to remove event... just not understanding what you want

Comment: @charlietfl your initial example is perfect, and it works perfectly for  switching on('hover') events to on('click') events if isTouchscreen is true, but I need the same logic to be applied for $('.foo').hover(); events as well, not only on('hover') events, understand?

Comment: @MHZ the `.click()` method triggers a `click` event; it's just a sugar method for `.trigger('click')`. Using the long-form you can pass your event variable in, switching for touch vs traditional. See the third example, [click() method with no params](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: OK... `$('.foo')['hover']();` is the same as `$('.foo').hover(); `..does that help? Instead of the "hover" string pass in `evt` smae way as the `on()` code I gave you. But...these can also be written using `on()` and do exactly same thing. jQuery uses `on()` internally to process `click()`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you always bind the 'on click' event. And conditionally, if touchscreen is false, also bind on hover event.